# How to export data from one MySQL table to another in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, data-transfer, data-export

Basically I have a client table and a leadlist for potential leads and I need to transfer the leads to the clients once they have been done, and delete them from the original table with an export button.

I've already tried a few possible things like `select from CData ......` and `insert into leadlist`, but it hasn't worked

My leadselect.php:

```
$(document).on('click', '.export', function(){
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to export this?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"export.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{user_id:user_id},
            success:function(data)
```

My export.php:

```
 <<?php

include('db.php');
include("function.php");

insert into leadlist
  select * from CData
 ?
```

button is defined as

```
$sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="export" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs export">Export</button>';
```

My expected result is for it to export the row of data that I choose to the leadlist and delete it.

Could you please advise me how I can approach this requirement?

Comment: You're not using `$_POST['user_id']` in `export.php`.

Comment: will that fix it ?

Comment: Do the `leadlist` and `CData` tables have the same columns?

Comment: ye exactly the same sorry i dont know if this is a stupid question or not im young and me and my friend have our own customer management systems company

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `$_POST['user_id']` in the queries to insert and delete the appropriate rows for that user.

Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection when using the parameter.

```
$insert_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO leadlist SELECT * FROM CData WHERE user_id = ?") or die($conn->error);
$insert_stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['user_id']);
$insert_stmt->execute() or die($insert_stmt->error);
$delete_stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM CData WHERE user_id = ?") or die($conn->error);
$delete_stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['user_id']);
$delete_stmt->execute() or die($delete_stmt->error);
```

Replace `user_id` in the queries with the actual name of the column that holds the user ID in your table.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8x9gf5imU8t28srzN8wJQp/0)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195962/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-how-to-export-data-from-one-mysql-table-to-anothe).